# Can I get ModalController by singleton?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

This is a very common usage of `ModalController`.

```js
constructor(private modalCtrl: ModalController) { }
```

However, I want to retrieve `ModalController` in a static context just like this,

```js
static showModal() {
  // `instance` or whatever
  ModalController.instance.create({
     /* .... */
  });
}
```

Is there any way to access the instance of services in Angular or Ionic?

Answer (score 0):

if you will use singleton in angular you can use services

https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { zip } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ModalService {
  private modals: any[] = [];
  constructor() { }

  add(modal:any){
    this.modals.push(modal);
  }

  remove(id:string){
    this.modals =  this.modals.filter(x=> x.id !== id)
  }

  open(id:string){
    let modal:any = this.modals.filter(x=>x.id === id)[0];
    modal.open();
  }

  close(id:string){
    let modal:any = this.modals.filter(x=>x.id === id)[0];
    modal.close();
  }


}
```